# Android saving pics to drawable

Tags: android

i wrote a small program to crop an image that is stored in the drawable folder. I am not able to figure out how to save the cropped image to the drawable folder !!

this is what i tried after seeing another stackoverflow post ..

```
try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/res/drawable/test2.png");
        bMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

where bMap is a bitmap object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not able to figure out how to save the cropped image to the drawable folder

You cannot "save the cropped image to the drawable folder". Resources are not modifiable at runtime. Please store it someplace else (`getFilesDir()`, etc.).

Comment: oh ok .. any way i can save the image somewhere and after program exec it moves it to drawable folder so next time the app runs i can open the cropped image ??

Comment: @Aado Droid: No. Just open it from the file you save it to.